# Algolia - WordPress - Exclude multiple taxonomies from indexing

Tags: wordpress, algolia

1) I am trying to exclude certain taxonomy from being indexed into Algolia. I can not make this work. This is my code:

```
function exclude_taxonomy( $should_index_category, WP_Post $post )
{
// Add all post types you don't want to make searchable.
$excluded_event_categories = array(
'post_type' => 'events',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'events_category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'xclude',
    )
),

);
if ( false === $should_index_category ) {
    return false;
}

return ! in_array( $post->taxonomy, $excluded_event_categories, true );
}

 // Hook into Algolia to manipulate the post that should be indexed.
 add_filter( 'algolia_should_index_searchable_post', 'exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );
```

2) how would I do this with multiple taxonomies. So I have second one which goes:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'events_status',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'archive',
    )
),
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is around the `$excluded_event_categories` variable.

I believe your code should should be something similar to the following snippet. If I understood correctly, you want to exclude `events_category` and `event_category` from being indexed.

```
function exclude_taxonomy( $should_index_category, WP_Post $post )
{
    if ( false === $should_index_category ) {
        return false;
    }

    return ! in_array( $post->taxonomy, array('events_category', 'events_status'), true );
}

// Hook into Algolia to manipulate the post that should be indexed.
add_filter( 'algolia_should_index_searchable_post', 'exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Julien Bourdeau - I need to exclude multiple taxonomies from multiple terms. So I need to get rid of 'archive' term from 'events_status' taxonomy AND I need to get rid of 'xclude' term from 'events_category' taxonomy.

Comment: Should it not be something like this:
function custom_should_index_terms( $flag, WP_Post $post ) {


    $excluded_ids = array( 3795, 1187 );
    if ( in_array( $post->term_id, $excluded_ids ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $flag;
}

add_filter( 'algolia_should_index_post', 'custom_should_index_terms', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'algolia_should_index_searchable_post', 'custom_should_index_terms', 10, 2 );